# Forecasting cash inflow using network load usage - timeseries vs GAM (or similar)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, generalized-additive-model, vector-autoregression

I have two datasets of daily cash_inflows & network consumption (load) for past 4 years. Network load consumption is the single source of income. There will be some lag between load consumption & the corresponding cash_inflow. i.e. cash_inflow today will be from the load consumption during last  month or quarter as customers pay bills monthly or quarterly. Moreover from data it looks like, certain day of the week (mostly Fridays)  has high cash_inflow , probably banks process payments in bulk. Also, one week of the month will have exceptionally high cash_inflow.

Daily data for the first year (365 days) is shown below, which shows a spike per week and an extreme spike every 4/5 weeks

[image]

I want to forecast cash_inflow for the next one month at a weekly level. I tried  Vector Auto regression (with load as a lagged variable), FB prophet & (auto) SARIMA-X both with no of holidays in the week, and load laggs of 1,2&3 weeks.

decomposed plot of the weekly timeseries is shown here
[image]

All models, especially VAR is able to capture the seasonality i.e. one spike a month. However they take  a conservative approach & fail to capture those extreme spikes. Moreover, the spikes forecasting slip by a week sometimes.

I am wondering whether timeseries analysis is the right approach or should I go for other approaches like GAM or similar.

Edit 2: Added daily box plot of individual datapoints. Some insights from further analysis :
[image]

- Most high value transactions happen on third Friday of the month.
- If that Friday is too early (e.g. 16th or 17th of the month), it slips to following Monday
- If that Monday is also too early, it slips to following Thursday.
- It happens on Tuesday & Wednesdays only if Monday (& Tuesday) are public holidays

Comment: Your plot does not look like it shows weekly totals. The highly regular pattern suggests that these are daily data, and you see the Friday effect. Correct? Also, you will likely need to *forecast* the load itself in a production environment, have you accounted for this? Please [take a look at this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352) about predicting spikes - if there is no signal in your data, then your model *shouldn't* predict them, because they are noise, and we should not chase noise. The key question is to identify a signal to predict the timing and height of spikes.

Comment: Thank you @StephanKolassa for your comment. I have added the daily plot for the first year, which shows the weekly spike (e.g. Fridays) & once in a month (4/5 weeks) extreme spike. I do agree with your point that we shouldn't chase the noise while forecasting. However, I am still confused whether those spikes are noise or signals. !

Comment: Thanks for the plot. These spikes are indeed intriguing, and their sheer regularity suggests that they can be forecasted. It looks like you should dig deeper into them. Do they always appear on a particular day of the week? And is the week always (say) the last week of the month, defined as (say) the week into which the last Friday of the month falls? Such a "last week" definition would lead to the spikes being sometimes 4 and sometimes 5 weeks apart. Domain knowledge may be helpful here, or you could possibly form assumptions that work well enough, and allow you to forecast the spikes.

Comment: I agree @StephanKolassa that we shouldn't be chasing the noises in the data. Thanks for pointing me to look deeper into those "last week" days. I have added the corresponding plot & my insights from further analyzing those extreme value days.

Comment: Hm. The pattern you have identifies sounds a little more complicated than I would have expected (which would have been something as in my last comment), so I would be afraid of overfitting. I recommend testing your ideas in a causal model, possibly with some seasonal model on residuals. Ideally, talk to some domain expert who can actually speak to the underlying data generation process.